# Hodge decomposition of the symmetric product of a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cohomology

Let X be a smooth projective connected curve over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $n>1$ be  an integer. Let $Y= Sym^n_X$ be the $n$-th symmetric product of $X$.

> > Is there, for every $i$, a nice formula for the Hodge decomposition of $H^i(Y,\mathbb{C})$?

If not, what  part of the Hodge diamond can be described easily?

Comment: Presumably you are aware of Macdonald's formula for the Poincaré polynomial of $Y$. There is an analogous formula for the Hodge polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Example $1.1$ in [this paper](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~maxim/sym_lib60.pdf) for a nice formula.

You can also compute them by hands (and, hopefully, prove the desired formula) by identifying $\mathrm{H}^{p,q}(\operatorname{Sym}^n X)$ with $S_n$-invariant part of $\mathrm{H}^{p,q}(X^n)$ (use the Kunneth's formula to compute the latter group).